# Increase tabular first and last padding

Tags: tables, margins, tabu

I use the [tabu](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf) package to typeset my table, mainly with `X` type column. My overall goal is to have the same inner padding between the table border and the text and between the text cells.

By default, LaTeX puts a `\tabcolsep` between every cell border (left or right) and the text. This means that between to texts, there will be two `\tabcolsep` but between the text and the border of the table there will be only one:

```
|__text__|__text__|
 1x      2x      1x
```

As I don't use vertical rule, I would like to have one `\tabcolsep` everywhere.

```
|__text__text__|
```

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{tableHeader}{RGB}{127, 12, 0}
\definecolor{tableLineOne}{RGB}{245, 245, 245}
\definecolor{tableLineTwo}{RGB}{224, 224, 224}

\begin{document}

    \taburowcolors[2] 2{tableLineOne .. tableLineTwo}
    \everyrow{\tabucline[.4mm  white]{}}
    \tabulinesep = ^4mm_3mm

    \begin{tabu}{X X X}
        \rowfont{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily}\rowcolor{tableHeader}
        Matiere & Note & Prof\\
        Francais & 5 & Melis\\
        Math & 5.5 & De Kempeneer\\
        Allemand & 4.5 & Bickel\\
    \end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

(Compiled with XeLaTeX)

Can anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a slightly odd request but you can make all the spaces `2\tabcolsep` by

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{tableHeader}{RGB}{127, 12, 0}
\definecolor{tableLineOne}{RGB}{245, 245, 245}
\definecolor{tableLineTwo}{RGB}{224, 224, 224}

\begin{document}

    \taburowcolors[2] 2{tableLineOne .. tableLineTwo}
    \everyrow{\tabucline[.4mm  white]{}}
    \tabulinesep = ^4mm_3mm

    \begin{tabu}{@{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}lll@{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}}
        \rowfont{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily}\rowcolor{tableHeader}
        Matiere & Note & Prof\\
        Francais & 5 & Melis\\
        Math & 5.5 & De Kempeneer\\
        Allemand & 4.5 & Bickel\\
    \end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! However it does not solve my problem. I want to add space _inside_ my colored lines. The `@{}` insert it before and after...

Comment: ah OK, You could instead do `>{\kern\tabcolsep}l` for the first column I suppose, and similar with `<` for the last.

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm for `l` column type! Does such an solution exists for X columns (from the tabu package)?

Comment: @Thib1235 no (not so easily), but you could put an empty l column at the front (but would need extra `&` on each row

Comment: Perfect! I was wondering however if there isn't a less *hacky* solution. But for now, it will perfectly do the job!